# Name/UID on page tab without authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, userid

I had previously thought there was no way to get a user's information, specifically their userid, without first getting them to authenticate your app. I see that this page, however, does that on a custom page tab:

http://www.facebook.com/AutoCADWS?sk=app_4949752878

Not only does this page tab get the viewing user's name, but it also gets their profile url, which includes their userid. How do they accomplish this without authentication? If this is possible, could someone point me to example code where I can see just how it implement it on my own page tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to uses FBML, which is **no** longer available for new Apps.

So, there is **no** way to do this **without** user authorization.